# Sending Variables to another HTML File

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a function that saves form data when the user hits submit.

```
function access(){
    var options = {};
    options.Email = $("#Email").val();
    options.First = $("#FirstName").val();
    options.Last = $("#LastName").val();
    var formData = JSON.stringify(options);  // Puts form data in one variable

    var params = new Object();

    $.ajax({
        url: "someURL",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: params,
        success function() { window.location = 'somePage.htm' },
        failure function () { window.location = 'errorPage.htm' }
    });
}
```

If there is a failure, it redirects the user to 'errorPage.htm' and that is where I will use the variable 'formData' from the access function to send an email. How do I pass the variable 'formData' to 'errorPage.htm'?

Comment: `YOUR_URL_HERE.htm?variable=YOUR_VALUE_HERE`

Comment: Why redirect user to another page for an asynchronous success or failure?  Why not display some sort of dialog? If you are going to redirect on success or failure, I guess I don't understand the point of using an asynchronous call pattern.

Comment: `'errorPage.htm?' + $("#formId").serialize();`

Comment: What is Obkect ? Why you sending object as param ? Post data as normal json string, or as Array.

Comment: In the failure page, the user will be allowed to type an email and it sends their form data.

Answer (score 1):

This is not ideal but you basically have to resort to query strings:

```
somePage.html?var=value
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
function access(){
var options = {};
options.Email = $("#Email").val();
options.First = $("#FirstName").val();
options.Last = $("#LastName").val();
var formData = JSON.stringify(options); <!--Puts form data in one variable-->

$.ajax({
    url: "someURL",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData ,
    success function() { window.location = 'somePage.htm' },
    failure function () {
         window.location = 'errorPage.htm?first=' + options.First +'&last=' + options.Last
    }
});
}
```